# Semantic tableaux generator

Tags: boolean-computation, trees, logic

I would like to use Mathematica to automatically generate a [semantic tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux) (truth tree) from a formula in propositional logic).

Here is an example formula:

$$(a \lor\lnot b )\land b$$

Here is the corresponding tree:

[image]

I am curious to know if anyone has tried to do this before. All ideas/help welcome.

For anyone interested: Here are the branching rules:

[image]

Finally here is the Mathematica code to manually create the tree (above).

```
description = {
  (a ∨ ¬ b) ∧ b -> b, 
   b -> (a ∨ ¬ b),
   (a ∨ ¬ b) -> ¬  b,
   (a ∨ ¬ b) -> a};

TreePlot[
   description,
   Automatic,
   (a ∨ ¬ b) ∧ b,
   VertexLabeling -> True]
```